# check if bash script input variable is a letter

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to write a short script to `ssh` to different servers depending on the argument I provide - if it is a number, I want the number to be a part of the server name, if it is a letter I want it connect to a certain server. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -eq ^[1,3-5]$ ]; then
        ssh -X servername1$1
elif [ $1=h ]; then
        ssh -X servername2
fi
```

but it keeps complaining that integer expression is expected and always tries to connect to servername2, no matter whether I give it a number or a letter.
I tried quotation marks around the first and the second comparison, I tried double equality sign in the second comparison - all to no avail. How can I make this work?

Comment: I guess, I found the solution. I cant make `-eq` work with `[1,3-5]`, but this works instead: `[[ $1 = [1,3-5] ]]`. If some could explain why, it would be great, since I made it work trying different solutions from the web. I would like to understand it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ $1 -eq ^[1,3-5]$ ]` is not bash syntax.

You can write like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 =~ ^[1,3-5]$ ]]; then
        echo "$1 integer"
elif [ $1 = h ]; then
        echo "$1 letter" 
fi
```

Output:

```
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ ./numorlet.sh 1
1 integer
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ ./numorlet.sh 3
3 integer
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ ./numorlet.sh 10
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ ./numorlet.sh h
h letter
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ ./numorlet.sh hhhh
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$
```

Also, tell me please, if the letter will be only 'h', or it can be any?
If any, use `[[` instead of `[` also in `elif` condition, with regex (I think `^[a-zA-Z]$` will work)

Comment: Got it now. I saw `=~` before, but I thought it was the not-equal sign. I see now that it is a completely different thing. Yes, the letter 'h' is just a letter that I picked to use as an argument for the script. It is easy to remember to use 'h' when I want to connect to 'hpc-cluster' node :).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a server list where you are taking the argument `$1` from.
If yes, you will have to do some changes in the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 -eq ^[1,3-5]$ ]]; then
        ssh -X servername1$1 < /dev/null
elif [[ $1==h ]]; then
        ssh -X servername2 < /dev/null
fi
```

SSH takes input from `stdin` by adding input from `/dev/null` you are telling ssh to take input from that specific file.

Using `[[...]]` tells that `if` has an expression.

you can read more about the `[[..]]` in [this link "Confused about operators"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Also `$1=h` is an assignment not a comparison; `==` is used for comparison.